# show validation in ajax in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have problem with ajax modal on my codeigniter project. I don't know why the submit button didn't work. the modal can be shown, but when I click the save button, nothing happens.

this is my javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo site_url('assets/js/jquery.js'); ?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo site_url('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js');?>"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('#submit').click(function() {
       var form_data = {
       name: $('#nama').val(),
       email: $('#email').val(),
     };
     $.ajax({
       url: "<?php echo site_url('adminproses/update'); ?>",
       type: 'POST',
       data: form_data,
       success: function(msg) {
        if (msg == 'YES')
            $('#alert-msg').html('<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your mail has been sent successfully!</div>');
        else if (msg == 'NO')
            $('#alert-msg').html('<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Error in sending your message! Please try again later.</div>');
        else
            $('#alert-msg').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">' + msg + '</div>');
    }
    return false;
});
});
```

this my modal form :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit-modal" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
     <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
         <h3 class="modal-title">Detail Data Anda</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body form">
        <form action="#" id="form" class="form-horizontal">
            <input type="hidden" value="" name="id_user"/>
                <div class="form-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Nomor Induk Pegawai</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input name="NIP" placeholder="Nomor Induk Pegawai" id="NIP" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $tampil['NIP'];?> ">
                            <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3">Nama</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                <input name="nama" placeholder="Nama Lengkap Anda" id="nama" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $tampil['nama'];?>">
                <span class="help-block"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3">Alamat</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                <textarea name="alamat" id="alamat" placeholder="Jalan A Nomor 1, Kelurahan A, Desa A, Kecamatan A, Kabupaten A, Provinsi A." class="form-control" ><?php echo $tampil['alamat'];?></textarea>
                    <span class="help-block"></span>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3">Nomor HP</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                <input name="no_hp" placeholder="081111111111" id="no_hp" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $tampil['no_hp'];?>">
                <span class="help-block"></span>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3">E-mail</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                <input name="email" placeholder="email@service.com" id="email" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $tampil['email'];?>">
                <span class="help-block"></span>
                </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-3">Kategori</label>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                    <select name="id_katuser" class="form-control" id="kategori">
                    <option value="">Pilih Kategori</option>
                    <?php foreach ($katuser as $kat){?>
                <option value="<?php echo $kat['id_katuser']; ?>" <?php if($kat['id_katuser']==$tampil['id_katuser']){echo "selected";}?>> 
<?php echo $kat['nama_katuser']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
    </select>
    <span class="help-block"></span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Username</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input name="username" placeholder="Username" id="username" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $tampil['username'];?>">
            <span class="help-block"></span>
            </div>
            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Password</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                                <input name="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $tampil['password'];?>">
                                                <span class="help-block"></span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div id="alert-msg"></div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                            </div>
                        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

and the controller :

```
public function update(){
    //set validation rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('NIP', 'nip', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nama', 'email', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('alamat', 'alamat', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Emaid ID', 'trim|required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('no_hp', 'no_hp', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('kategori', 'kategori', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

    //run validation check
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){   
        //validation fails
        echo validation_errors();
    }
    else{
        //get the form data
        $NIP = $this->input->post('NIP');
        $nama = $this->input->post('nama');
        $alamat = $this->input->post('alamat');
        $no_hp = $this->input->post('no_hp');
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $id_katuser = $this->input->post('kategori');
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
    }
}
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: save button should be of type="submit" and it should be inside the form tag

Comment: ok, thank you for the correction @Aashu. But now when I click the save button, the page is reload and the address bar show the values in my form.

Comment: In your code there is no element with id="submit", however you want to call the click on such element  ($('#submit').click(function() {)

Comment: Thank you for the correction @Zaragoli. My form values shown in the address bar now.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to post the data

```
$('#btnSave').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
     var form_data = {
         name: $('#nama').val(),
         email: $('#email').val()
     };
     $.ajax({
         url: '<?php echo site_url('adminproses/update'); ?>',
         type: 'POST',
         data: form_data,
         success: function(msg) {
             if (msg == 'YES')
                 $('#alert-msg').html('<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your mail has been sent successfully!</div>');
             else if (msg == 'NO')
                 $('#alert-msg').html('<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Error in sending your message! Please try again later.</div>');
             else
                 $('#alert-msg').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">' + msg + '</div>');
         }
         return false;
     });
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Arjun. I've checked my code and I found that the form didn't works woth the ajax, so the url in the ajax canntor be executed. That's why when I click submit, all of the values in the form are shown in the address bar. After I edit my code, it still like that :(

Comment: Raka : when you click on button with preventing its default action it will do post the data with form reload so you are getting the data in the url.

Comment: I have updated the answer so please use the above code.
Your selector and the id of button did not match so the ajax was not working.